# I cannot install packages anymore with pipenv

Tags: python, pipenv

Each time I want to do pipenv install the package is not installed.

I guess it is because of geckodriver but I don't know why.

Error:

```
✘ Locking Failed! 
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26_2/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 69, in resolve
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=requirements_dir
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26_2/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 726, in resolve_deps
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=req_dir,
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26_2/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 480, in actually_resolve_deps
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       resolved_tree = resolver.resolve()
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26_2/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 395, in resolve
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure: ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches geckodriver
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       No versions found
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches geckodriver
No versions found
Was https://pypi.org/simple reachable?
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=requirements_dir
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26_2/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 726, in resolve_deps
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=req_dir,
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26_2/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 480, in actually_resolve_deps
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       resolved_tree = resolver.resolve()
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26_2/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 395, in resolve
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure: ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches geckodriver
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       No versions found
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches geckodriver
No versions found
Was https://pypi.org/simple reachable?
```

Comment: Could you add your `Pipfile` above.  Are you trying to install a package named `geckodriver`?  Because I can't find any such package on PyPI.

Comment: I did not use a Pipfile this is why. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Check your **pipfile** and **pipfile.lock** file. You probably don't have them present. You need to specify the package you want to install otherwise.